# One of my objects doesn't appear in 3D View Full

Tags: modeling, materials, objects, 3d-view

For my imaging and modeling class, we are to make an animation as part of our final. I've imported 4 objects from Slicer into Blender and have the animation that I want down.

However, one of the objects (Corpus) isn't visible in 3D View Full, and if I assign it a material, the material doesn't show up.

This is my first time working with any animation software and I'd appreciate any help.

[Here is the blend file.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d3u3agoe2lmj7hu/Skull.blend?dl=0)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Corpus is created from individual edges but not **Curves**. As far as Blender is concerned it has no mass and there is nothing to render.

Go to the **Object** menu and **Convert To** select **Curve From Mesh/Text**.

Now you can go into the **Curve** settings and **Extrude** to give the threads depth.